# Custom Methods now defined by the cocoa library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was asked this question during a technical discussion and can't seem to find answer anywhere.

The problem:

If I wrote methods by extending a core class (Lets say `NSArray`) which didn't exists in iOS 5 but were introduced in iOS 6.

What would happen to my application in the app store when the user upgrades to iOS 6? Would it crash? Would it be refer to foundation class? Would the runtime point to my function and everything will continue to work same?

Eg.

iOS 5.0

`PGMyArray` : `NSArray`

```
- (NSString) info; // convert and concatenate each object of the array into a string.
```

Now in iOS 6.0, Apple introduced the method publicly as part `NSArray`

`NSArray`

```
- (NSString) info; // Does exactly same as my method
```

What would happen when user upgrades to iOS 6.0 and my application calls

```
PGMyArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[myArray info];
```

My intelligent guess is, it would still be calling to PGMyArray-> info (after looking up from virtual table). However, I wasn't told the right answer and its bothering me for weeks now.

Any explanation / help is appreciated.

Comment: I once wrote this exact example to test it and see what would happen. I'm too lazy to find it to find the results though.

Comment: I could not find an `info` method of `NSArray`. Was this meant as a theoretical example?

Comment: yes. Its a theoretical example.

Answer (score 2):

As you know any subclass can override an existing method. Even here you will end up with calling your method. i.e. **Overriding** it.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you shouldn't call it "info". You should use a three letter prefix (two letter prefixes are reserved by Apple), like abcInfo.

Comment: prefix are for ClassNames not for properties or categories.

Comment: Possibly find the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388440/xcode-4-5-warns-about-method-name-conflicts-between-categories-for-parent-child

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Of course it makes sense to prefix category methods to avoid name conflicts.

Comment: @MartinR: I never used any prefix, till now for methods(category), as never thought of overriding or such a method-name-conflict!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are *extending* the NSArray class, it means that if you implement a `info` method, YOUR method will be called, because you are *ovveriding* the default `info` method.

It is the same when you implement some methods like the `viewDidLoad` method. You have to implement it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Your initialization
}
```

You have to call the *super* method because you are overriding it, meaning that the super class viewDidLoad method is not called anymore.